# Shortes axis perpedincular to longest axis?

Tags: geometry

Assume you have $N$ circles, each of radius $r_i$, in general $r_i\neq r_j$ when $i\neq j$. The circles lie in the $xy-$plane, where they are allowed to intersect. I can find the vector that points both along the long axis $\vec{v}_l$ and the vector that points along the short axis $\vec{v}_s$ of the circle arrangement.

[Circles in plane. The magenta axis points along the longest axis and the red along the shortest.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbFHf.png)

I have the conjecture that the vector that points along the long axis is **always** perpendicular to that of the short axis; namely, $\vec{v}_l\cdot\vec{v}_s =0$.

Is there any way to prove/disprove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a counter example to the conjecture. Here is the diagram. Sorry.

[Counter example for the conjecture $\vec{v}_l\cdot\vec{v}_s=0$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6DEH.png)